# Video of Shinichi Mochizuki skype conference

Tags: reference-request, soft-question, abc-conjecture

In late 2015, Shinichi Mochizuki gave a skype conference to mathematicians about his IU Teichmuller theory. I have tried to find videos of that conference but my efforts have been in vain.

Do you know where I can find them, if there are any?

Thank you.

Comment: The "official" website of the conferenz you are refering to (and you might know) is [here](https://www.maths.nottingham.ac.uk/personal/ibf/files/kyoto.iut.html). There are the slides of the talks, but no protocoll or dump of the skype session with SM.